# Div CSS Transition Direction

Tags: jquery, css, transition, direction

I was wondering if it's possible to control the direction a CSS transition starts from.

I've created a div that will expand in height on hover; however, it's at the bottom of the page and causes the scrollbar to expand downwards.

Conveniently, I would like the div to expand upwards rather than having an anchor point at the top which causes it to expand downwards. Hope this makes sense.

Your help is appreciated with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably have to make the position fixed or absolute with a `bottom:0` set.

Comment: have tried `transform-origin: x-offset y-offset`

Comment: Can you add a sample code / JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your element in a relative positioned one.
Then, set `position: absolute; bottom: 0` on your element :

```css
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.back-to-top {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    transition: height .5s;
}
.back-to-top:hover {
    height: 50px;
}


/* Style only */
.back-to-top {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e74c3c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent.
</p>
<br>
<div class="relative">
    <a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to the top</a>
</div>
```